# GCC for ARM is linking in extra data

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, newlib

I'm currently trying to upload some code onto an LPC810, which is a Cortex-M0+ microcontroller. I have a simple progam I'm trying to use, which just blinks an LED on and off.

```
typedef unsigned int volatile * vp;

int main()
{
    *(vp) 0x4000C1C0 = 0xFFFFFFBFUL;
    *(vp) 0xA0002000 |= 1 << 2;
    for(;;) {
        *(vp) 0xA0002300 |= 1 << 2;
        volatile long wait = 240000;
        while (wait > 0) --wait;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: This file is called `main.c`.

I didn't write this code, but I know that it works. The problem is that when I compile this into a binary file to upload, it turns out to be on the order of 75 kiB! That's way too large for my microcontroller.

After running `size` on the elf file, there seems to be a bunch of extra functions and data being linked in. I'm using newlib.

Below is my Makefile. I'm sure that its probably something to do with my compiling/linking flags, but I've been unable to figure it out.

```
PROGRAM=hello
ARCH=arm-none-eabi

CC=$(ARCH)-gcc
CXX=$(ARCH)-g++
OBJCOPY=$(ARCH)-objcopy
OBJDUMP=$(ARCH)-objdump
NM=$(ARCH)-nm
SIZE=$(ARCH)-size

FLAGS=-pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wfatal-errors -O3 \
    -fdiagnostics-color -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb
CFLAGS=-std=c11 $(FLAGS)
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++14 $(FLAGS)
LDFLAGS=

OBJECTS=./obj/main.o

all: ./$(PROGRAM).hex

run: ./$(PROGRAM).hex
    sudo lpc21isp -wipe -verify -bin ./$(PROGRAM).hex /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 12000
    make clean

./$(PROGRAM).hex: ./$(PROGRAM).elf
    $(OBJCOPY) ./$(PROGRAM).elf -O binary ./$(PROGRAM).hex
    $(OBJDUMP) -D $< > $(PROGRAM).disasm
    $(NM) -n $(PROGRAM).elf > $(PROGRAM).sym
    $(SIZE) $(PROGRAM).elf

./$(PROGRAM).elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

./obj/%.o: ./src/%.s
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

./obj/%.o: ./src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

./obj/%.o: ./src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm $(OBJECTS) ./$(PROGRAM)*
```

I'm generating a binary file with a hex extension with this, so sorry about any confusion.

Any thoughts on how to fix this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you need the standard library? You could compile with `-nostdlib`. You can also strip symbols with `-s`. This also may be helpful: [Reducing Executable Size](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Reducing_Executable_Size).

Comment: @John The `-s` flag doesn't seem to do anything to the size. I don't need the standard library proper, but the `-nostdlib` flag also removes the linker script and other startup code that I _do_ need. Besides that, that flag is what I need, but I haven't found a way around that problem. Still, thanks for the reply!

Comment: After `-nostdlib`, you can add `-lgcc`, which should setup for main, but will not include exit handlers, etc.  You may generate a mapfile `-Map=project.map` and look at what is linked (and why).  Really if you are doing this and concerned, you should not use `main()`, but `_start:` and clear *.bss* yourself and setup the stack.  Probably you need a custom linker file.  They you will know when unintended floating point/div, etc are used. I have made ARM Linux user-space code <1k like this.  I am sure there is code floating around for this CPU if you look hard enough.

Comment: @artlessnoise I've tried that in the past but linkers have always gone a bit over my head. But, maybe it's time for me to give it a shot again though. I also tried those flags and renamed `main` to `_start`, but still being in C the linker probably didn't find it properly. When I launch the code, nothing happens, so it probably wasn't in the right spot in memory. I'll give a custom link script and startup files a shot again though, thanks.

Comment: Here is [the first thing](http://eleceng.dit.ie/frank/arm/BareMetalLPC812/index.html) that [google LPC810 bare metal](https://www.google.ca/#q=LPC810+bare+metal) returns.  It has a tar file with source that is doing exactly what I was talking about *init.c*; there are probably other examples...  His blinking light code is about 512 bytes..

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest to link with linker option `--gc-sections`. This should strip all unused library stuff.

Thus, add `-Wl,--gc-sections` to your LDFLAGS.

However I am pretty sure that your compiler's output is not that big as you think. I assume that your binary file contains lots of zeros. Actually I assume you have less than 265 Bytes of payload and the rest is zero.
This is because your output is linked not to address zero. Check your ELF file with `arm-none-eabi -e hello.elf`. (You're application code is there in section `.text`)

To fix this I am pretty sure you have to learn how linker scripts work. Checkout the manual "The GNU linker" for this.

Comment: Fortunately, I was able to get this up-and-running with a custom linker script, but I will try that flag in the future if the problem returns. And while I left the detail out, my programming tool (lpc21isp) complained about running out of sectors to program, so I _think_ that it was actually large. As far as I could tell, it was newlib, my libc, that was causing the bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Optimize binaries for space with -Os, not -O3, strip symbols with -s, and get rid of the stdc++ libraries you are linking in (std=c++14), that's not even a C++ program!

Comment: I've tried `-Os` and it removes a couple bytes, but not much more (which is consistent with past experience). I'm still left with about 75k, `-s` has no effect at all, and the c++ flag is not activated because my file is `main.c`, not `main.cpp`, sorry for not specifying that. Instead, `-std=c11` is active.